# Plotting a 3D array of points in Blender

Tags: import

I have a 3D array of points which was generated from an experiment. I would like to plot them in space so that I can then make animations with it. Is it possible to import arrays of points into blender and plot them in 3D (in my case it would generate a surface)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give an example of the format that the points are stored?

Comment: Yeah, we need more information to be able to help you. "*Is it possible to import arrays of points into blender?*" it is, but the real question is, can your data be exported in a format that Blender can understand and import? What formats can you export to? Also "*in my case it would generate a surface*" this will most likely need to be done manually.

Comment: Hi! Yes thanks - they were initially in .h5 format and I'm using them in Matlab so I also have them in .m format. I could probably get the points into an excel file too.

Comment: Not really sure if Blender can read that. Unless you want to get into scripting you might need export it in some other more common file formats, like 3Ds or OBj perhaps

Comment: if those are XYZ points coordinates, you can also use a python script to read the values and create geometry. Or, you could also try http://www.meshlab.net/ to interpret those points, and then late rexport some mesh object to blender